# Segfault with ctypes when returning a struct - 32 bit linux

Tags: python, linux, ctypes

so I am getting a segfault from ctypes on a 32 bit linux machine that I can't reproduce on 64 bit darwin or linux.

Here is the C:

```
typedef struct {
  void *ptr;
  } doodle;

doodle C_intpointerfunction(int *a)
{
  *a = 41;
  doodle foo;
  foo.ptr = a;
  return foo;
}
```

which is compiled with:

```
gcc -c intpointerlibrary.c
gcc -shared intpointerlibrary.o -o libintpointerlib.so
```

and here is the Python:

```
import numpy as N
from ctypes import *

_libintpointer = N.ctypeslib.load_library('libintpointerlib.so','.')

_libintpointer.C_intpointerfunction.restype = c_void_p
_libintpointer.C_intpointerfunction.argtypes = [POINTER(c_int)]
def P_intpointerfunction():
  lrc = c_int(0)
  print "lrc before (should be 0) = "+str(lrc.value)
  return_val = _libintpointer.C_intpointerfunction(byref(lrc))
  print "lrc after (should be 41) = "+str(lrc.value)
  return return_val
```

so now, when I call this function:

```
  rc = P_intpointerfunction()
```

I get a segfault.  I've tried creating a Python class to wrap the returned struct that is created on the C side with the same results.  If passing back a native ctypes type (like c_int) everything works fine..  Is this truly just a problem with 32 bit Linux, or is there something I have not considered?  Thanks!

Comment: Don't hold out on us.  You got a segfault but we don't see the stack trace. :)

Comment: Well I don't know HOW to get a stacktrace in this case..  I tried gdb but it doesn't recognize python..  any suggestions on how to accomplish that in this mixed language scenario?

Comment: For future reference: I did figure out how to use gdb in this scenario.  I put a time.sleep(30) at the beginning of the python code, called it in the background, started gdb, and 'attach #####', then 'continue', then 'backtrace'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you're setting `restype = c_void_p`;

```
class DOODLE(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('ptr', c_void_p)]
_libintpointer.C_intpointerfunction.restype = DOODLE
```

works as expected for me, on Linux x86-64.

Comment: Well, I guess I didn't know any better.  Anyway, this works perfectly, thanks!  such an easy solution to a problem that I have been trying to ignore for weeks!